# Android Studio not running application

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-build

I'm having an issue where the app I'm working on is not deploying to the device when I'm ready to test it out. It used to do it just fine, but then I updated to 5.0.1 Lollipop, which I believe to be the culprit. Besides downgrading back to 4.4.4 KitKat, which is quite the process on my bootloader-locked Galaxy S4, what can I do to resolve this? ADB recognizes my device and the project builds with no errors/warnings. However, the app does run and work normally if I build the signed APK manually and send it to my device via email/PushBullet which is just a lot of extra, unnecessary steps.

I'm sorry for the lack of information, I'll update as tips come along as to what I've tried. I don't know where to start. One thing I have tried was changing all compile sdk versions to 21, but no dice. It does pop up with the green bubble "session 'app' running" but nothing happens on the device. Also, the ADB pane reports "no debuggable applications." The big issue here is that I can't debug my applications at this point since I can't view the logcat. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really sure it isn`t being deployed at all? What is the output in the Run tab?

Comment: DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.harmonicvibration.orbit"
Aborted


Launching application: com.harmonicvibration.orbit/com.harmonicvibration.orbit.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.harmonicvibration.orbit/com.harmonicvibration.orbit.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Aborted

Comment: Have you restarted all devices involved? Your PC, the smartphone? And have you tried restarting the ADB deamon?

Comment: Yes to all 3 of those

Comment: And if you go through the app drawer in your device you can't find your app at all?

Comment: Can you try it with some other device to confirm that the is an issue with this specific smartphone or if there might be some more general problem on your PC?

Comment: I have also faced similar issue on studio.I make some changes and run again and it seems to work fine second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out on my device (Galaxy S4 Lollipop) they added a security feature which didn't allow for ADB installs. The solution was to get root permissions and install [**adbd Insecure**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd&hl=en) app from Chainfire and run it. Works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 1):

My phone has SuperSU (a rooting app) which updated and caused this problem. As part of the update it had switched off the preference to allow processes running as system user to gain root access without confirmation. I simply enabled the 'Trust system user' option and it worked as normal.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Please un install the application if already installed and install again.
there is a kind of issue that application installed but not auto launched. You nee to launched explicitly but If app is already installed then you can't identify that your new installation works or not.

Once un install and install again and track if found installed.

Open the "Edit Configurations" pane and click the '+' button. Select the option to create a new 'Android Application' and then select the correct module. Apply, and you can then delete the test configuration you were using before if you wish. Then everytime you run, make sure you are running as an Android Application and not a test and it will auto-launch on install.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing please tell.?
Please also check that is there any of the compile library defined more than one times in gradle file.?

Comment: Check the accepted answer. I found the solution to my issue. The app compiled and ran just fine on my 4.4.4 KitKat device. But when I upgraded the device to 5.0.1 Lollipop, the app would not install. The solution was to override a security feature.

Comment: IN Android Lollipop 5.0.1, there is another kind of feature of multi user. Just open notification bar, and see with the setting icon, there is another icon for user switch. When you installed application on a single user and the application is not from the play store(As in your case you are installing from Android Studio), then the app is also installed on other user's(user available) space. in that case if you tried to install this app then it may cause different signature. So you should remove this application by going all the users then install again.

Comment: I only have one user on the device anyways